# How to invoke a click on the map - BingMaps?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm working on a Bing Maps web application. I have a click listener that fires when any location is clicked on the map. Is there any way to fire this listener manually simulating a click on a location with specified coordinates? I've been able to do this with Google Maps but so far I haven't found a way to do it on Bing Maps?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke an event by using the appropriate `invoke` method from the `Microsoft.Maps.Events` class, for example on a pin:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.invoke(selectedPin, 'click');
```

See the reference on the MSDN: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427623.aspx